# linux environment command line arguments

Tags: c++, linux

I am a Windows programmer and now I am learning to program in Linux environment, I use LinuxMint15.

I encountered a "weird" problem that the command line arguments were not what I typed.
The program is super simple:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    printf("cmd line=");
    for(int i=0;i<argc;i++){
        printf("%s ", argv[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Then compile and run it, it works as I wanted:

```
roy@xx ~ $ gcc -o cl test_cl.cpp
roy@xx ~ $ ./cl 1 2
cmd line=./cl 1 2
```

But when I typed a * at the end, it listed all filename in the folder.....:

```
roy@xx ~ $ ./cl 1 2 *
cmd line=./cl 1 2 Public Template Video Picture Docs Desktop cl test_cl.cpp test.txt untitled
```

What happened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most Linux shells treat the characters `?` and `*` specially. In particular, they are used for globbing patterns to match against file names. In this case, the shell expands the `*` to all files in the current directory and then sends that list to your program as command-line arguments. If you want a literal `*`, you need to escape it with `\*` or quote it with `'*'`.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt answer, yes I noticed \\* works too, but I wonder if there is somewhere that I can change the default behavior of the shell?

Comment: No, you don't want to change the default behavior of the shell. You need your shell to behave as others (and the POSIX standard) expect!